# Acces vertex pos, normal and color in VTK from an OBJ import

Tags: python, opengl, vtk, vertex

I want to do a raycast between two OBJ meshes that I import with vtkOBJReader. I want to do a raycast from the vertex point to the direction of the normal toward the second mesh.

However I do not know how to access the vertices (and the params) from the first mesh. I am bit confused abt the concept of cell and points and the filters in vtk.

What I manage to do so far was to create a vtkCellCenters object and retrieve the normal and point from it to do my raycast but this is not really what I want...

Here is how I can access the cell center and normal to start my rayCast:

```
import vtk

OBJ_SCALE = 100.
ColorBackground = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
FirstobjPath = r"...my Path to the first OBJ file..."

reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()
reader.SetFileName(FirstobjPath)

# I scale up object for better precision
transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
transform.Scale(OBJ_SCALE, OBJ_SCALE, OBJ_SCALE)
transformPData = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
transformPData.SetTransform(transform)
transformPData.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

# I transform poly to triangle for proper indexing
triangles = vtk.vtkTriangleFilter()
triangles.SetInputConnection(transformPData.GetOutputPort())

# Here is how I get my cell data
cellCenterCalc = vtk.vtkCellCenters()
cellCenterCalc.SetInputConnection(triangles.GetOutputPort())
cellCenterCalc.Update()

# I can get the point center with this
pointsCellCenters = cellCenterCalc.GetOutput(0)
# and the normals with this
normalsCalcScan = vtk.vtkPolyDataNormals()
normalsCalcScan.SetInputConnection(triangles.GetOutputPort())


mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(triangles.GetOutputPort())   
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
ren.SetBackground(ColorBackground)
ren.AddActor(actor)
```

I need to be able to do the same thing but with vertex pos and normals (I also like to have access to the vertex color to use it as a mask for filtering which vertex should do the raycast)
I am thinking something like that but no luck so far :S any help is much appreciated ;)

```
polyData = triangles.GetOutput()
polyData.GetCellData().GetScalars("Colors")
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with that too. Here is how I access vertices and faces in C++. I hope in Python it is similar - when written *vtkSmartPointer< vtkXXXX >*, just focus on *vtkXXXX*

```
void accessEachVertex( const vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>& mesh )
{   
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> vertices = mesh->GetPoints();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> verticesArray = vertices->GetData();

    long long numberOfVertices = vertices->GetNumberOfPoints();

    // access 3D coordinate [x, y, z] of each vertex 
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++ )
    {
        float x = verticesArray->GetComponent(i, 0);
        float y = verticesArray->GetComponent(i, 1);
        float z = verticesArray->GetComponent(i, 2);

        ....
    }
}

void accessEachFace( const vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>& mesh )
{
    int  numberOfFaces = mesh->GetNumberOfCells();

    // acces each mesh face. A face is defined by the indices 
    // of the participating vertices.
    // this mesh has triangle faces - therefore three vertices.
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++)
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> face = vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();
        mesh->GetCellPoints(i,face);
        int v0Idx = face->GetId(0);
        int v1Idx = face->GetId(1);
        int v2Idx = face->GetId(2);

        // see the accessEachVertex function
        // to read the coordinate of vertex v0Idx,
        // v1Idx or v2Idx
    }
}
```

Here is an [example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/PolyDataExtractNormals) how they access the different type of normals. Honestly, I have some troubles with the normals in vtk. In some cases they are just absent or much more likely, I am not able to find them :) Anyway, I compute them my self in [computeVertexNormalsTrivial](https://github.com/eidelen/DicomToMesh/blob/master/vtkMeshRoutines.cpp). Hope you can take something from this answer.